# JQuery Ajax Submit Form - Getting response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am posting a form using Jquery Ajax...this is the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


            //callback handler for form submit
$("#myform").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            //data: return data from server
            alert('it worked');
            alert(this.data + "," + this.url);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails   
            alert('it didnt work');   
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind();
});

$("#myform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM

});
```

This works fine and onsucess I've added this:

alert(this.data + "," + this.url);

And it's giving me the posted data and url.

My problem is that the api that it's submitting to returns data like this after the form is submitted:

```
<response>
<result>12</result>
<message>Successful.</message>
</response>
```

What I want to do is to be able to get that response.

How can I get this info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace `this.data` with `data`, and if you want to access a particular field of the response, add the JSON `dataType`:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        ...
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            alert("Result: "+data.result+", Message: "+data.message);
        },
        ...
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Alert(data); is returning: [Object XMLDocument]

Comment: Arf, I thought it could handle XML data. So just to see the result in the console, use "json" as `dataType`

Comment: Avoid using Alert as the data cannot be displayed correctly most of the time, and use the Console instead

Comment: dataType: "text", seems to show all ... But how would I get a particular field? tried: alert(data.result); but it returned nothing

Answer (score 1):

you can refer bellow example .

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
  });
```